# How does Azure determine an instance is not working or is unhealthy?

Tags: azure

I have an app in azure configured with 10 instances. Now if an instance is not working the load balancer should remove and replace it with a new one.
But some of the jobs that run on the instance are very cpu intensive and can take up to 30-60min. So in effect the app is not unhealthy , it is just processing data.

Would health check deem it as unhealthy , cause i dont want to remove it , as it will casuse an error in the job processing.

So how can i make sure that Health Check in Azure only removes "non-responsive / unhealthy" instances ?

UPDATE: Powershell script

```
 $instances = @("instance1.example.com", "instance2.example.com", 
"instance3.example.com")

foreach ($instance in $instances) {
$result = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $instance -Port 80 - 
  InformationLevel Quiet

if (!$result) {
    Write-Host "Instance $instance is not responding."
    # You can also take additional actions here, such as sending 
    notifications or triggering failover mechanisms.
}
```

}

Comment: Which Azure Service are you using? VM Scale Sets, App Services, Functions, etc...?

Comment: Can you check this [blog](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/09/azure-app-service-health-check.html#:~:text=You%20can%20further%20control%20the%20Health%20check%20behavior,to%20avoid%20overwhelming%20the%20remaining%20healthy%20instances.%20) if this works for your scenario. @Traci

Comment: It is an azure app service written in .net.  I have read the "blog" but it doesnt seem to accommodate for the scenario if an app is running a long running process and consumes lots of cpu and memory ; the instance is not unhealthy , just taking a long time ?

Comment: Yes I am saying about app setting `WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES`. @Traci

Comment: I am now using a powershell script and updated the question . I think that may work , what do you think ?  That is from an example , but for the instance would the url be the instanceUrl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does Azure determine an instance is not working or is unhealthy: -

*Use below PowerShell script to retrieve the web app instances and test if it is healthy or not.*

As you've given, using `Test-Netconnection` works in your case and I modified your code accordingly.

```bash
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
$context=Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscriptionId>"
$accesstoken = Get-AzAccessToken
$Headers=@{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'='Bearer '+ $accesstoken.Token
}
$instances=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<WebApp>/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $Headers
$instances.value
$instances.value.id
$machineName=$instances.value.properties.machineName
foreach ($machine in $machineName) {
$result = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $machine -Port 80 -InformationLevel Quiet
if (!$result) {
    Write-Host "Instance $machine is not responding."
}
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They all return a $result of false ?

Comment: It depends on the machine which you are trying to test the connection. @Traci